# What is the equivalent of @WebParam in C# .NET?

Tags: java, c#, asp.net, web-services

I'm fairly new to c# .Net and supposed to convert a project from java to c#, i got stuck trying to convert these 2 methods (the first method records the date when ever its called  "when a transaction happen", and calls the second method which has all the logic) but the problem is the second method parameters are WebParam and i cant find the equivalent of that in c# (i tried looking it up but i still don't get it) hopefully someone can point me to the right direction, thank you in advance.

the first method:

```
    public String writeStudentPayment(String st_no, String depositID, double requiredAmount, double depositAmount,
                                  String RegYear, String RegSmst, String accountID, String BankID, String BranchID //,                                                
                                            //@WebParam(name = "Branch_User_Name") String branch_userName,
                                            //@WebParam(name = "Branch_Password") String branch_pwd
                                         )
{
        Date d=new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        DateFormat frmt=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        String  strDate=frmt.format(d);
        return writeStudentPayment(BankID, BranchID, depositID, requiredAmount, depositAmount, strDate, accountID, st_no,RegYear,RegSmst); //,branch_userName, branch_pwd);
}
```

the second method:

```
    @WebMethod(exclude = true)
private String writeStudentPayment(   
                                            @WebParam(name = "Bank_ID") String bankID,
                                            @WebParam(name = "Branch_ID") String BranchID,
                                            @WebParam(name = "Deposit_ID") String depositID,
                                            @WebParam(name = "Required_Amount") double requiredAmount,
                                            @WebParam(name = "Deposit_Amount") double depositAmount,
                                            @WebParam(name = "Deposit_Date") String depositDate,
                                            @WebParam(name = "Account_ID") String accountID,
                                            @WebParam(name = "BAU_ST_NO") String st_no,
                                            @WebParam(name = "Reg_Year") String RegYear,
                                            @WebParam(name = "Reg_Smst") String RegSmst //,
                                            //@WebParam(name = "Branch_User_Name") String branch_userName,
                                            //@WebParam(name = "Branch_Password") String branch_pwd
                                  )
{ // the rest of code.................}
```

Comment: are you sticking with SOAP? are you using WCF?

Comment: @ATerry tbh im not sure what a WCF is cuz i have 0 knowledge in asp.NET but yeah i believe they are sticking with SOAP

Comment: WCF is Microsoft's API for SOA. It differs from Asp.Net which is an API specifically targeting HTTP. WCF has all the features to build a SOAP API over whatever protocol. Asp.Net probably can build SOAP APIs but would probably need some external libraries and workarounds. This doesn't answer your question, but I would look at WCF instead of Asp.Net. BTW you just need to specify the param in your service contract if you are using WCF.